# reformatting invalid date(String) to a valid format

Tags: php, date

i'm reading dates from a website which uses user friendly dates like

`Friday - 7/18/2014 1:00 AM`

i need to read these date as an valid php readable date something like

`2014/7/18 1:00 AM`

i can remove `Friday` easily

$date = end(explode(' - ' , $date));

but re formatting current `d/m/Y` to `Y/m/d` using the same method would be messy and i like to do it in a clean way if possible ... bsically i want to avoid `explode` and  `list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use `DateTime::createFromFormat ( string $format , string $time )`

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("l - n/j/Y g:i A", "Friday - 7/18/2014 1:00 AM");
```

Then you can output it with `echo $date->format($format)`, and use the formats specified here: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: that's what i want , thax